# Cannot create a database on a fresh installed monetdb

Tags: database, monetdb

I'm new using `MonetDB`. I've follow this installation guide http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Guide/Installation
and I'm facing a problem to just create a database. Here is the error

```
monetdb create /tmp/c
monetdb: cannot find a control socket, use -h and/or -p
```

Ruuning the command with option `-p`or `-h` didn't change anything

```
monetdb -p create /tmp/c
monetdb: cannot find a control socket, use -h and/or -p
```

can come one help me ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `monetdb` you need to call `monetdbd`.

Comment: Also note that the prepackaged versions of monetdb on Linux distros often create a farm in a root accessible only directory as part of the install, which means that:

1) you want be able to start a new process with default port, you will have to use a different port or shutdown the default one

2) alternatively you can run the monetdb "create" and "release" commands as root.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't start (and even create) a dbfarm. The dbfarm is a directory that contains all the database instances that you create.

You should follow the [tutorial](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you also can have an issue with the root access. I recommend creating the folder for MonetDB's data farm on your own:
mkdir /tmp/c
monetdbd create /tmp/c
monetdbd start /tmp/c
monetdb create db_name
monetdb release db_name
mclient -u monetdb -d db_name
pass: monetdb

Answer (score 0):

try to run command as `monetdb` user

```
sudo -u monetdb monetdb create database_name
```